# replace XMLHttpRequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, browser

I used to read my local files using XMLHttpRequest.

```
function getData(fileName)
{
  var filePath = fileName;
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  var fileContent = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var tempArr = csv2Arr(fileContent);
  var returnLabelArr = tempArr[0].toString().split(',');    
  tempArr.shift();
  var returnDataArr = tempArr;
  return { 'dataArr' : returnDataArr, 'labelArr' : returnLabelArr };
}
```

fileName starts with "C://..." and my program works on browser with address "file:///...".

But, without "--allow-file-access-from-files" tag, my code doesn't work on Chrome. And also it doesn't work on IE and Firefox without changing some security options.
So, I tried to jquery API like this,

```
function getData(fileName)
{
var filePath = fileName;
var fileContent;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: filePath
})
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
    fileContent = data;
});

var tempArr = csv2Arr(fileContent);
var returnLabelArr = tempArr[0].toString().split(',');  
tempArr.shift();
var returnDataArr = tempArr;
return { 'dataArr' : returnDataArr, 'labelArr' : returnLabelArr };
}
```

The Problem also occurs. I think [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents it.

Can anyone give me some suggestions for me to access local files without changing security options? Should I use some plug-ins to solve this?

Please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `<input type="file">` to select files, then the solution is:

HTML:

```
<form action="">
     <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpeg" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file-input');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var files = fileInput.files;
    if (files.lenght == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        readFile(files[i]);
    }
    fileInput.value = "";
 }, false);

 var readFile= function(file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
         var dataUrl = e.target.result;

         // now, load the data into some element
         // if this is image, you can do this:
         var image = new Image();
         image.src = dataUrl;
         document.body.appendChild(image);
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 };
```

Also, discover the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to find out, how you can use it otherwise, as it has more methods to read data.

Comment: I cannot use <input type="file">. is there an another method to solve this?